# Cant get my third screen working ubuntu 18.04 amd ryzen 5 2400g

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors

I've just got myself a new computer and would like to use ubuntu as my operating system. However it does not seem to use all three of my screens.

I have the following relevant hardware:

- MSI B350M (this has 1 hdmi port, 1 dvi-d and 1 displayport)
- AMD ryzen 5 2400G

**What have I tried?**

So when I connect my third screen over displayport without other screens on it does turn on during the bootscreen, eliminating the possibility of a defect in the cable, monitor or gpu.

I have tried installing the AMDGPU-PRO driver but without success, Ubuntu doesnt boot after installing.

I have contacted AMD and they said that the only drivers they offer are for windows. So now I'm not sure if it is possible at all.

I have tried using a older version of ubuntu (16.04) with the same results

**More information**

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-A-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

error messages in dmesg:

```
[    0.000000] ACPI Error: [SMIC] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/dswload-378)
[    0.000000] ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-252)
[    0.000000] ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, (SSDT:  AMD PT) while loading table (20170831/tbxfload-228)
[    0.000000] ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 7 successful (20170831/tbxfload-246)

[drm:log_to_debug_console [amdgpu]] *ERROR* TG counter is not moving!
[    0.705572] AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter.
    0.835097] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[    0.835119] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[    0.837090] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[    1.209263] [drm:log_to_debug_console [amdgpu]] *ERROR* No EDID read.

[    1.265380] [drm:generic_reg_wait [amdgpu]] *ERROR* REG_WAIT timeout 1us * 100 tries - tgn10_lock line:566
[    1.270164] [drm:log_to_debug_console [amdgpu]] *ERROR* TG counter is not moving!
[    1.270191] [drm:log_to_debug_console [amdgpu]] *ERROR* GSL: Timeout on reset trigger!
```

**The problem**

After all this trying I'm not sure what to do anymore. And would like to get some help getting this working.

NOTE: The dvi-d and hdmi screen do give output but as soon as I use the dislayport it does give me a black screen after some text showing up.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't suppose you have tested it with windows?

Comment: I will add the output to the post, I have tried windows for a bit but it took 3 hours to update and the drivers refused to install. So I have removed windows again, and just installed a clean install of ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Would be helpful to have output of `xrandr` with all displays attached and powered on.  It would show whether the computer is even able to detect the displays as connected.  Also, what is the "some text showing up"?  Any error messages in `dmesg`?

Comment: I will add in all errors I can find.

Comment: The support for the APUs is still not perfect. You may very well be hitting a bug in the kernel. Have you opened a bug report on the matter? You can run `ubuntu-bug linux` to open a bug report.

Comment: Also whomever you talked to at AMD didn't know what they were talking about, I guess. AMD contributes directly to upstream kernel and Xorg, as well as providing the proprietary Pro version of the AMDGPU driver for vulkan/opencl 2/etc… Support staff are I guess not so well informed. :(

Comment: I think most support staff don't expect linux users. Shall I refference this post in the bug report?